# In recursive DP, break up recursion call by storing variables: inefficient?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, temporary-objects

Suppose I am solving a dynamic programming problem recursively (top down). For example, a recursive solution to the longest common subsequence problem:

```
LCS(S,n,T,m)
{
if (n==0 || m==0) return 0;
if (S[n] == T[m]) result = 1 + LCS(S,n-1,T,m-1); 
else result = max( LCS(S,n-1,T,m), LCS(S,n,T,m-1) );
return result;
}
```

Often in such a DP problem at some point we have to take the max of some expressions, representing returns to different choices we can make. In the above case we have the max of two simple expressions, but in worse cases it can be the max of three or four quite complicated expressions involving long function calls. In such situations, I am often tempted to give these complicated expressions their own variable names, to make the code more readable. In the above case that would mean I would write

```
LCS(S,n,T,m)
{
if (n==0 || m==0) return 0;
if (S[n] == T[m]) result = 1 + LCS(S,n-1,T,m-1); 
else
    a = LCS(S,n-1,T,m);
    b = LCS(S, n, T, m-1); 
    result = max(a, b);
return result;
}
```

(In this simplified case `a` and `b` are not complicated, but in other cases they are, and there may be even more arguments to the max function, so this could really help it be more understandable.)

**My Question:** Is this a terrible idea? As I understand it, I'm adding a variable to each layer of the call stack, and I'm thinking that could be wasteful. But on the other hand, at each layer it has to calculate the temporary variable `LCS(S,n,T,m)` anyway (I'm thinking in terms of C++, say), and as far as I know, there might be not much difference in cost between the two ways.

If this is a terrible idea, is there a more efficient way to break up a complicated recursive function call to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has the "As-If" rule, which states that a compiler can do whatever it wants so long as the observable effects are indistinguishable from what is defined by the standard to happen. In this case, it's trivial to prove both fragments have the same meaning, and a compiler will likely emit identical instructions for both.

Note: You aren't doing dynamic programming here, as you don't memoise parameter / result pairs.